# How to control the v-for times dynamically?

Tags: vue.js

How to control the v-for times dynamically?

I have a case, I want to generate `1->10` divs:

```
<div v-for="item in 10" style="background-color: red" >{{ item }}</div>
```

and I want to control the counts dynamically, it maybe `1->3`, `2->8`, `5-6`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `v-if`:

```
<div v-for="item in 10" v-if="item >=min && item <= max" style="background-color: red" >{{ item }}</div>
```

you can change the `min` and `max` dynamically.

Comment: using `v-for` and `v-if` on the same component is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a property of your component's data as the number:

```html
<div v-for="number in count">{{ number }}</div>
```

If you want to start counting from a different number, you can use a property for that too:

```html
<div v-for="number in count">{{ start - 1 + number }}</div>
```

See it here in action: https://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/vjKBRg